# Ambiguous left join?

Tags: mysql, join, ambiguous

so I'm struggling with what I'm guessing is a very simple problem. I've searched around a bit, but none of the solutions I've found so far have worked on my problem.

```
SELECT arrangement_ID, hva, dato 
FROM tt_arrangement LEFT JOIN (tt_vaktliste_vakt)
ON (tt_arrangement.arrangement_ID = tt_vaktliste_vakt.arrangement_ID)
```

This naturally produces the "ambiguous error", since the column 'arrangement_ID' is present in both tt_arrangement and tt_vaktliste_vakt. Thinking this was easy to fix, I made the following changes:

```
SELECT **arrangement_ID.tt_arrangement**, hva, dato 
FROM tt_arrangement LEFT JOIN (tt_vaktliste_vakt)
ON (tt_arrangement.arrangement_ID = tt_vaktliste_vakt.arrangement_ID)
```

However, this produced the error "column doesn't exist". And that's where I'm stuck.
Not sure if it matters, but when using SELECT * the query works as intended. Though that is not really an option for what I'm going to use the query for.

In advance, thanks for any replies.

Comment: You have it backwards - it's supposed to be [tablename].[columnname] not [columnname].[tablename].

Comment: Haha, thanks. Guess I've been working too long, starting to go code blind ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix the ambiguous column name with the tablename:

```
SELECT t_arrangement.arrangement_ID, hva, dato  
FROM tt_arrangement LEFT JOIN (tt_vaktliste_vakt) 
ON (tt_arrangement.arrangement_ID = tt_vaktliste_vakt.arrangement_ID)
```

(assumes hva, dato are unique column names)

(You can also use aliases, but will still need to prefix ambiguous column names with alias)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your table names an alias, like below.

```
SELECT a.arrangement_ID, a.hva, a.dato 
FROM tt_arrangement  AS a
LEFT JOIN tt_vaktliste_vakt AS v
ON (a.arrangement_ID = v.arrangement_ID)
```

Not sure is the top lines right as i don't know you table structure so can't know which column comes from where.

Hopes this helps.